# Configuration property name 'My.data' is not valid:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

## **Bean**

```
package com.LoadDataFromYMLResource.Beans;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Component
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "My.data")

public class DifferentDataTypes {

    private int port;
    private String url;
    private boolean active;

    private List<String> models;
//    private Set<String> models;
//    private String[] models;

    private Reference refObj;
}
```

## YAML Code

```
My:
  data:
    port: 2020
    url: jdbc-oracle-3030
    active: true
    models:
      - M1
      - M2
      - M3
    refObj:
      db: oracle
```

## **OutPut**

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Configuration property name 'My.data' is not valid:

```
Invalid characters: 'M'
Bean: differentDataTypes
Reason: Canonical names should be kebab-case ('-' separated), lowercase alpha-numeric characters and must start with a letter
```

Action:

Modify 'My.data' so that it conforms to the canonical names requirements.

I am trying  to load data from ymal to my bean but it showing msg like this

Comment: Reason: Canonical names should be kebab-case ('-' separated), lowercase alpha-numeric characters and must start with a letter


LOWERCASE

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is, and what you need to do to resolve it. What specifically are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

Try **lowercase** in class and properties (my.data)